# Adding sidebar to Debut Theme Shopify

Tags: shopify

Anyone that has the code for adding a sidebar to the Debut Theme for my categories?
Because I want to add a sidebar, but it is not possible without code.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following HTML code, You can create a sidebar view in your required page.

```
   <div class="page-width">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid__item small--one-whole medium-up--one-third">
            // Sidebar code here...
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid__item small--one-whole medium-up--two-thirds">
            // Main content code here...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```